# ajax reply working but when it load second times

Tags: ajax

I am updating my cart quantity using ajax. After successfully updating of the cart, when I load the cart and body of the current page the toggle menu of the my cart button does not work the first time. But when I update second time after loading the cart and body the toggle menu works.

My current code:

```
'remove': function(product_id, flag) {
    // alert(product_id);
    // alert(flag);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'includes/addToCart.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'product_id=' + product_id + '&flag='+flag,
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('#cart > button').button('loading');
        },
        complete: function() {
            $('#cart > button').button('reset');
        },
        success: function(json) {
            // Need to set timeout otherwise it wont update the total
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('#cart > button').html('<span class="lg">My Cart</span><span><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i> ('+json['total']+') items</span>');
            }, 100);
            setTimeout(function () {
                // if(json['key'] == "blank")
                $('#cart > ul').load('includes/loadcart.php');
            }, 100);
             setTimeout(function () {                   
                $('body').load('cart.php');
             }, 100);
        },
    });
```

In the console I am getting this error when it executes:

```
    Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of 
    its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience.
```

I have used the async: true, and async: false
same problem persists

here is my html code where the value displayed

```
<div class="btn-group btn-block" id="cart">
              <button class="btn btn-viewcart dropdown-toggle" data-loading-text="Loading..." data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" aria-expanded="false" id="cart_total"><span class="lg">My Cart</span><span><i class="fa fa-shopping-basket"></i> (<?=$_SESSION['totalitem']?>) items</span></button>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right" ><li>
                  <table id="cart_item" class="table table-striped">
                            <tbody>
                             <?php
             if(empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td align="center" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 14px;" colspan="5">Your Cart Is empty</td>                
            </tr>
            <?php
            }
            else{
            $subtotal = 0;
            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $key=>$value){
                $subtotal = $subtotal + ($_SESSION['cart'][$key]['price']*$_SESSION['cart'][$key]['qty']);
            ?>
                              <tr>
                      <td class="text-center">            <a href="#"><img class="img-thumbnail" title="iPhone" alt="iPhone" src="../photo/<?=$_SESSION['cart'][$key]['img']?>" width="57px" height="57px"></a>
                        </td>
                      <td class="text-left"><a href="product.php?id=<?=$_SESSION['cart'][$key]['id']?>"><?=$_SESSION['cart'][$key]['name']?></a>
                                    </td>
                      <td class="text-right">x <?=$_SESSION['cart'][$key]['qty']?></td>
                      <td class="text-right">$<?=$_SESSION['cart'][$key]['price']*$_SESSION['cart'][$key]['qty']?></td>
                      <td class="text-center"><button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" title="Remove" onclick="cart.remove('<?=$_SESSION['cart'][$key]['id']?>','delete');" type="button"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                  }
                }
                   $vat= $subtotal * (20/100);
                                  $total = $subtotal + $vat;
                  ?>
                                  </tbody></table>
                </li><li>
                  <?php
                    if(!empty($_SESSION['cart']))
                    {
                    ?>
                  <div>
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                                <tbody><tr>
                        <td class="text-right"><strong>Sub-Total</strong></td>
                        <td class="text-right">$<?=$subtotal?></td>
                      </tr>
                                <tr>
                        <td class="text-right"><strong>Eco Tax (-2.00)</strong></td>
                        <td class="text-right">$2.00</td>
                      </tr>
                                <tr>
                        <td class="text-right"><strong>VAT (20%)</strong></td>
                        <td class="text-right">$<?=$vat?></td>
                      </tr>
                                <tr>
                        <td class="text-right"><strong>Total</strong></td>
                        <td class="text-right">$<?=$total?></td>
                      </tr>
                              </tbody></table>
                    <p class="text-right"><a href="cart.php"><strong><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> View Cart</strong></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="#"><strong><i class="fa fa-share"></i> Checkout</strong></a></p>
                  </div>
                  <?php
                }
                ?>
                </li></ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: So many questions. Why use a bunch of separate times instead of one function? Why not rely on returned data to determine the total instead of pretending a time delay is sufficient? Why use *multiple* async loads and how everything happens in the right order? You might want to take a step back and spin through some tutorials on how async programs work, how to order dependent calls, and how to use data and callbacks properly.

Comment: All that said, except for the highly-suspicious use of timeouts and probably not getting things loaded in the right order, there's not enough context here to help any further.

Comment: You lost everything when you overwrite it with `$('body').load('cart.php');` there... and "toggle menu works" - what toggle menu.  Please update your question with a more complete set of code including what you allude to as a "toggle menu".  Note that `async: false` is deprecated and will be removed so do NOT use or rely on that.

Comment: timeouts to "make something work" in JavaScript typically mean something is wrong that needs fixed in your design and the use of those WILL fail, unpredictably and in hard to diagnose ways.